# Looping over a Dataframe in R by column names

Tags: r

I am an R novice that is trying to analyze some batch data from a computational model. I have two files, a batch parameter file and the raw output data. I'm trying to make a general R code which will take in the batch parameter file, determine the variables which were varied, and output statistics about the raw data based on those variations. To determine which variables had a range of values (rather than a constant) I tried the following code:

```
for(i in names(params.no.constants)) {
if (length(levels(factor(params.no.constants$i))) > 1) {
var.values <- factor(params$i)
params$i <- factor(params$i)
#code to process this parameter
}
}
```

The idea is to factor the numeric data in the batch parameters, see if it has more than 1 level, and if so, assign it to my iterator variable (var.values), factorize that variable in the parameter list, and then go process the corresponding data from the raw data file. Is there a way to access the elements of the data frame in the way I am approaching it? Or perhaps a more elegant data access scheme?

EDIT 1: I found a solution, but to me it is pretty smelly code. I applied the factor operation to the parameters before the loop, used eval and parse to construct my variable, then did the operation as before. I'd still like if there were a more elegant answer.

```
params.no.constants <- lapply(params.no.constants,factor)
for(i in names(params.no.constants)) {
k <- eval(parse(text=paste("params.no.constants","$",i,sep="")))
if (length(levels(k)) > 1) {
var.values <- levels(k)
#code to process this parameter
}
}
```

EDIT 2: based on the comment below, simpler code for variable k assignment:

```
k <- params.no.constants[[i]]
```

Comment: There are probably more "elegant" ways, but to solve your immediate problem do `params[[i]]` instead of `param$i` (and everywhere else you do `$i`). `$` doesn't do any evaluation, it will literally look for a column called `i`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be a way to do that type of data access but I didn't know the syntax.